# How to change the button image when button pushed

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the button pic when button is touched.

I try a few ways ,but in vain.

I think this is quite basic question though, there is a plenty of samples to set initial images, but cant find the dynamically assigned way.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image imgLevel = Image.asset('images/LL_Normal.png');

    FlatButton fbLevelBtn = 
      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          debugPrint("test ok”);
          imgLevel = Image.asset('images/LL_Hard.png'); // it doesn’t work..
          this.child = Image.asset('images/LL_Hard.png'); // it doesn’t work..

        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: imgLevel
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the picture in the build method instead:

```
bool isPressed = false;

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Image imgLevel = isPressed  ? Image.asset('images/LL_Normal.png') : Image.asset('images/LL_Hard.png');

        FlatButton fbLevelBtn = 
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              debugPrint("test ok”);
              setState(() => {isPressed = true});

            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: imgLevel
          );
```

Comment: THank you it solves my problem, setState() is still a bit complex to understand though....

Comment: Some simple clarification on setState:
By calling the setState() function, you are saying "my widget needs to update, so please schedule an update and rebuild". Also, you pass in a closure / anonymous function, to setState, and this function will be called during that update. So whatever you write within setState ( () => {//code goes here }), will be executed in the scheduled update, not before, so here you usually set the variables you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you press the button? Cause it seems that you are missing the setstate function

Comment: I see I need to understand setState() more.